# WebDriverException Error for Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, robots.txt

Trying to send commands using my test_ios_app.robot file to the iphone

Already started web driver agent runner, running at port 8100

```
*** Settings ***
Library AppiumLibrary
*** Variables ***
${REMOTE_URL} http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8100/
${PLATFORM_NAME} iOS
${PLATFORM_VERSION} 12.1
${DEVICE_NAME} iPhonesimulator
#Appium uses the *.app directory that is created by the ios build to provision the emulator.   
${APP_LOCATION} /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-ezvfffwkjpaaegaeahoqnwqrrqrc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/IntegrationApp.app
${BUNDLE_ID} com.facebook.IntegrationApp-testnblog

*** Keywords ***
    Open App
    Open Application ${REMOTE_URL}
    platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME}
    platformVersion=${PLATFORM_VERSION}
    deviceName=${DEVICE_NAME}
    app=${APP_LOCATION}
    automationName=appium
    bundleId=${BUNDLE_ID}

Close All Apps
    Close All Applications

*** Test Cases ***
test_demo    
    Open App    
    Close All Apps
```

Not too sure what is going on. I started the app on xcode and sent the command --> Robot test_ios_app.robot and it showed me this error.

[image]

Seems like there is something wrong with my REMOTE_URL?

Please feel free to let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Are "platformName", "platformVersion" etc part of the arguments you want to pass to the keyword? Cause it looks like so, but with this indentation - being on new lines, they are not. See the log, the only argument being passed is REMOTE_URL. Fix the arguments being passed, and if there is still a problem, add the full exception message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i forgot to start the appium server by doing *appium &*

So there were some connection problems.

Here is a really good guide that helped me to resolve my problems.

http://testnblog.com/ios-automation-with-appium-1-6-robot-framework/